# Why does open set never go to 0?

Tags: python, algorithm, pygame, a-star

I am trying to create the A Star algorithm and apply to the game Snake. The problem I'm having is that I never get anything drawn on the window  because it never reaches that code. It gets stuck when trying to calculate the path in the method run(). Specifically, open set never goes to zero and it adds already existing nodes.

I've tried printing the various lists to the console, but all i've discovered is that "current" repeats tiles at random points, and "openSet and "closedSet" continue to get larger with these repeated tiles. I've also tested my Tile object, my contains method, and my giveNeighbors method and all of these seem to be working and give the expected results. Also as a reference, I am going of the pseudo code found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

```
import Tile
import pygame

class A_star:
def __init__(self):
    self.closedSet = []
    self.openSet = []


def run(self, start, goal):

    self.closedSet = []
    self.openSet = [start]
    path = []

    #THE LENGTH OF OPEN SET NEVER GOES TO ZERO!
    while len(self.openSet) > 0:
        #Set current to node in openSet with lowest fscore
        current = self.openSet[0]
        currindex = 0
        for i, node in enumerate(self.openSet):
            if node.fScore < current.fScore:
                current = node
                currindex = i

        #romove from Open set and add to closed
        self.openSet.pop(currindex)
        self.closedSet.append(current)

        #Reached the end        
        if current.tileEquals(goal):
            print("Done")
            while current != None:
                path.append(current)
                current = current.cameFrom
            return path[::-1]

        neighbors = self.giveNeighbors(current)

        print("Current: " + str(current.posx) + ", " + str(current.posy))

        print("Neighbors")
        for i in neighbors:
            print(str(i.posx) + ", " + str(i.posy))

        for i in neighbors:
            #if neighbor is already checked, then ignore it.
            if not self.contains(self.closedSet, i):
                #Distance between start adn neighbor. tenative gscore
                tempGScore = current.gScore + 1

                #if neighbor is not in openset. Discovered a new node!
                if not self.contains(self.openSet, i):
                    self.openSet.append(i)
                elif tempGScore < i.gScore:
                    i.gScore = tempGScore
                    i.cameFrom = current
                    i.fScore = i.gScore + self.heuristicCost(i, goal) #f = g + h

        print("Open:")
        for i in self.openSet:
            print(str(i.posx) + ", " + str(i.posy))
        print("Closed")
        for i in self.closedSet:
            print(str(i.posx) + ", " + str(i.posy))


#Calculates the estimated distance from a given tile to end
def heuristicCost(self, neighbor, goal):
    #The snake never goes diagonal, therefore calculate manhatten distance
    distance = abs(neighbor.posx - goal.posx) + abs(neighbor.posy - goal.posy)
    return distance

def giveNeighbors(self, current):
    neighbors = []
    if current.posx > 0:
        neighbors.append(Tile(current.posx - 10, current.posy))
    if current.posx < 200:
        neighbors.append(Tile(current.posx + 10, current.posy))
    if current.posy > 0:
        neighbors.append(Tile(current.posx, current.posy - 10))
    if current.posy < 200:
        neighbors.append(Tile(current.posx, current.posy + 10))

    return neighbors

def contains(self, s, tile):
 for i in s:
    if i.tileEquals(tile):
        return True
    else:
        return False



def testAStar():
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
pygame.display.set_caption("AStar Test")
window.fill((255,255,255))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

start = Tile(0, 0)
end = Tile(190, 190)

astar = A_star()
path = astar.run(start, end)

run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 255, 0), (start.posx, start.posy, 10, 10))
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), (end.posx, end.posy, 10, 10))


    for i in path:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 0, 255), (i.posx, i.posy, 10, 10))

    print("drew stuff")

    pygame.display.update()
    window.fill((255,255,255))
    clock.tick(10)

pygame.quit()


if __name__== "__main__":
    testAStar()


class Tile:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.posx = x
            self.posy = y
            self.fScore = 0
            self.gScore = 0
            self.cameFrom = None

    def nextTileRight(self):
            self.posx = self.posx + 10

    def nextTileDown(self):
            self.posy = self.posy + 10

    def nextTileUp(self):
            self.posy = self.posy - 10

    def nextTileLeft(self):
            self.posx = self.posx - 10

    def tileEquals(self, t):
            if self.posx == t.posx and self.posy == t.posy:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

The expected result should be a non-diagonal path drawn on the window from the start node to the end node. (Also, sorry if my indentation is off. I am still very new to this website)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are checking openSets == 0 , you are looking for currentNode = destination or all the neighbours are closed meaning everything has been checked and no path was found.